# UseThymeleaf template view with retrieve data from database to another template view

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to include the view service which already retrieve data from my database to my index.html page. I'm using Spring and Thymeleaf.

This is my service controller

```
    @Controller
public class MyServicesController{
    @Autowired
    private ServicesForOurServices servicesForOurServices;

    @RequestMapping(value = "myservices",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myServices(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("services",servicesForOurServices.listAll());
        return "services";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "services",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listAll() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("services");
        modelAndView.addObject("services",servicesForOurServices.listAll());
        return modelAndView;
    }


    @ModelAttribute("services")
    public Iterable<MyServices> services() {
        System.out.println("Inside service without model");
        return servicesForOurServices.listAll();
    }
}
```

And my service template view

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Services</title>

    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> /*/-->
</head>
<body th:fragment="services">
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(services)}" class="container-fluid text-center" id="services">
        <h2>SERVICES</h2>
        <h4>What we offer</h4>
        <div th:each="service : ${services}">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span th:class="${service.getIcon()}"></span>
                <h4 th:text="${service.getName()}"></h4>
                <p th:text="${service.getDescription()}"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I include the fragment to my index.html

```
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="services :: #services"></th:block> /*/-->
```

But the index.html only render the h2 and h4 tag and not the div containing the services

[image: But the index.html only render the h2 and h4 tag and not the div containing the services]
and if I access the services.html everything renders fine
  [image: and if I access the services.html everything renders fine]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspect the elements from your browser to see whether there is any error fetching pictures? Suspecting the URL is incorrect after rendering.